# IE 11 Edge DevTools no Computed styles

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ie11-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug why a component element is rendering differently on IE11 but the DevTools for both IE and Edge are finding no css in the Styles or Computed tab. How to I debug this properly?

Left to right: IE11, Edge, Chrome
[image]

Edit 1:

It appears to be any component under `router-outlet`

Answer (score 1):

under the computed tab, click the silhouette in `{}`. That will show you all of the styles for that element. For whatever reason, the logic for showing the specific rules that apply to that element from your stylesheet appears to be broken.

Comment: Toggled the silhouette. Still nothing.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an open source project and I can't duplicate out side.

Comment: without a reproduction we won't be able to help. let me know if you want to make your private code available to the edge team to help.

Comment: I have noticed too that sometimes the styles do not show in IE11 at all. It helps to restart the browser and try it again. I am using Angular and it seems that it is too much work for IE to compute :)